# Como crear una carpeta en el root principal de la memoria interna de android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, archivo, programación-móvil

Estoy intentando crear una carpeta en android al momento de llamar al método makeDir("CarpetaCreada") me la crea en la siguiente ruta:

/ROOT/Android/data/com.NombreAPP/files/CarpetaCreada

```
package com.example.liferegisterdiary;

import android.content.Context;
import java.io.File;

/*
* This is a file and folder controller 2021
* Here you create and read files and folders.
*/
public class FileFolderController {
    /*
    * In MainActivity.java
    * Context context = this;
    * and then
    * fileFolderController = new FileFolderController(context);
    */
    Context context;
    public boolean mkdirStatus;

    public FileFolderController(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mkdirStatus = true;
    }

    public boolean makeDir(String folderName) {
        try {
            String intStorageDir = this.context.getExternalFilesDir("") + "";
            File newFolder = new File(intStorageDir, folderName);
            return newFolder.mkdirs();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean existsDir(String folderRoute) {
        try {
            String intStorageDir = this.context.getExternalFilesDir("") + "";
            File newFolder = new File(intStorageDir, folderRoute);
            return newFolder.exists();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que yo deseo es saber como el método makeDir("CarpetaCreada") me cree una carpeta en el root ... es decir, que no se vaya hasta Android/data/com.NombreAPP si no que me la cree en la raíz principal.

osea
/ROOT/CarpetaCreada

Comment: Me apuesto algo a que, cómo mínimo, tu aplicación necesitará permisos especiales. Y eso si no es que necesitas que esté el terminal en modo gdb o incluso rooteado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anteriormente se podía, pero **a partir de Android 10 se definió que no puedes crear archivos o directorios fuera de la estructura de la aplicación**, únicamente podrás crear archivos o directorios dentro de :

```
/Android/data/<package name>/files/
```

no importa si usas `getFilesDir()`  o `getExternalFilesDir()`

Comment: Entonces como hace? whatsapp o voice recoide o el 90% de las APP que instalo para crear carpetas en el root?

Comment: Algunas de estas aplicaciones que pueden escribir en otra ubicación son "aplicaciones de sistema", tienes permisos root en el dispositivo?